# How to display image with png or Jpeg format in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

i want to load a image rather than .bmp format in installer.Can anyone help me to display image with JPEG or PNG format.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do that.All you can do is use **MS Paint** or download **[Format factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com)** 
and convert the image into .bmp format.